# How to remove creation of file paths?

Tags: files

I have created a Drupal project, on that project I have many files uploaded. But when I crawl the project through crawlers I am getting files as file url like the following.

`http://project.com/files/file2png`
  This means I have a file in my files directory as `file2.png`
`http://project.com/files/file1png`
  This means I have a file in my files directory as `file1.png`

I have a **File Entity** module. Does it create url in this format?
If yes, how to avoid this?

And I don't know which module makes this. I want to avoid this. Is there any way to remove creation of file paths for my files?

Comment: Avoid this? What is this?

Comment: Actually I have file uploaded in my files directory, but drupal creates a file as a file path like the above. That means if I goto the above URL I can see the EDIT button on the page there is a option to replace the image.

Comment: So do you mean you want to avoid this pages discovered by the crawler?

Comment: I don't want to create pages for the Files

Comment: Can you add these explanations in the question and even change the title? It help others to have a better understanding to your question.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, would you update the question for others which can make other easy to search for the same thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment:

> I don't want to create pages for the Files

The url `file/%file` is registered as menu item in `file_entity_menu()`. You can disable the page by implementing [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x) in custom module.

**Example**

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // disable the file entity page
  $items['file/%file']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

Another question you mentioned.

> Can I redirect to home page for file url's?

You can override the page callback and add the redirection in it.

**Example**

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // disable the file entity page
  $items['file/%file']['page callback'] = 'mymodule_file_callback';
}

function mymodule_file_callback($file) {
  drupal_goto('<front>');
}
```

Comment: It works well... I have a doubt, If I use this means this won't create page? And how about if already URL is created?

Comment: `hook_menu()` acts as a route and not creating physical url for you. Every request will try to lookup the pattern of all menu items and try to find out the match one and return the page. So when you set it inaccessible, the page won't be generated and will redirect to the suitable page which show that you don't have the right to access.

Comment: Can I redirect to home page for file url's?

Comment: You can do it by override the `page callback` in the menu item. You can redirect to anywhere you like in your custom page callback. It is the Drupal way. You can achieve the same thing in .htaccess as well if you prefer that.

Comment: Can I you show me a example for this?

Comment: @PraveenSrinivasan I've updated answer.